# Overriding django form in Forms.modelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-modeladmin

I have a problem when I want to override a field in my form

The class looks like below

```
   class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['password', 'services', 'project', 'email', 'name', 'first_name', 'role']
```

I want to modify the field 'Services' with another value.
For this I used the get_form function like this :

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      exclude = ('uuid',)
      search_fields = ('email', "project")
      list_display = ("email", "project", "nb_connexion")
      form = UserCreationForm


    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj != None:
            print(obj.name)
            print(request)
            form = super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
            form.base_fields['services'].initial = Service.objects.filter(projects=obj.project)

        return form
```

But I still get the same results for all the services while I am only interested in getting the services of one project.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: but how i can fill the list with just the 'services' of the user, ?

Comment: Note that your form may not handle hashing the `password` field correctly. You could look at extending the `UserCreationForm` and `UserAdmin` from Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently trying to set `initial`, which is the initial value selected. If you want to limit the choices, you want to override the `queryset` instead.

You can alter the form's fields in the `__init__` method:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['password', 'services', 'project', 'email', 'name', 'first_name', 'role']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['services'].queryset = Service.objects.filter(projects=self.instance.project)
```

Your `UserAdmin` class already uses `form = UserCreationForm`, so all you have to do is remove the `get_form` method.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    form = UserCreationForm
    ...
```